# Angular: How can i use ng-repeat conditionally?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to print out a schedule where every week something happens on a Monday and two other days of the week that alternate every other week.

The intended output is:

---

Monday

Wednesday

Friday

---

Monday

Tuesday

Thursday

---

Monday

Wednesday

Friday

---

Monday

Tuesday

Thursday

---

Monday

Wednesday

Friday

---

Every week Tuesday alternates with Wednesday and Thursday alternates with Friday.

Here is my data:

```js
$scope.weekdays = [
 {name: 'Monday'},
 {name: 'Tuesday'},
 {name: 'Wednesday'},
 {name: 'Thursday'},
 {name: 'Friday'},
];
```

Here is my code:

```html
<div ng-repeat="i in numOfWeeks(5) track by $index"> //numOfWeeks returns array of length 5
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="day in weekdays">
   {{day.name}}
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make it conditionally display the days of the week so that it outputs the desired results.

The example only shows 5 weeks but in reality it will be many weeks which is why i'm trying to figure out how to do it programatically.

Thank you.

Comment: You could probably use a filter on the `day in weekdays` bit based off of the week number (if 0/2/4/6 [even] show Mon/Tue/Thur, else [odd] show Mon/Wed/Fri or vice versa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom filter function that takes a week number as a parameter to determine which array filter to apply. The example below applies a simple filter based on whether the week number is odd or even (that works for your example) - `weekNo % 2` - but it could contain any type of logic.

```
$scope.filterDay = function(weekNo) {
  return function(day) {
    if (weekNo % 2) {
      return ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Thursday"].indexOf(day.name) > -1;
    } else {
      return ["Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday"].indexOf(day.name) > -1;
    }
  };
};
```

And you apply it like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="week in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]">
  <div ng-repeat="day in weekdays | filter:filterDay(week)">
    {{day.name}}
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Pho2eNit1wCbT0pJxmA?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  You and everyone else makes this community so great.

Looks like I needed to read up and learn about filters.  Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data structure isn't set in stone, just change it to be more friendly to what you're trying to accomplish.  I.E.  make an array of weeks, and put into them whatever days they're supposed to have.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to get to here, but lets say it was a calendar app.  So your days would actually have properties too.  You did mention that you have appointments on those days, so why not go with an actual OO approach, and make them that way

```
Day1 = { name: 'Monday', appointmentHourStart: '12', appointmentHourEnd: '14'};
Day2 = { name: 'Tuesday', appointmentHourStart: '12', appointmentHourEnd: '14'};
Day3 = { name: 'Wednesday', appointmentHourStart: '8', appointmentHourEnd: '10'};
Day4 = { name: 'Thursday', appointmentHourStart: '12', appointmentHourEnd: '14'};
Day5 = { name: 'Friday', appointmentHourStart: '10', appointmentHourEnd: '12'};
Week1 = { Day1, Day2, Day4 };
Week2 = { Day1, Day3, Day5 };
.
.
.
etc.

Weeks:    [ Week1, Week2, Week3, etc.]
```

Then you have your object to iterate through -

```
<div ng-repeat="Week in Weeks track by $index">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="day in Week">
            {{day.name}} :: {{day.appointmentHourStart}} - {{day.appointmentHourEnd}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can easily shove a collection of whatever you want to call your "Daily" objects into the Weeks array.  Then use your same setup to iterate through the weeks, and then iterate through the days.

If there is a constraint around the data, can you give me a little more explanation around what the constraint is and if there's any other constraints.  If there's not a constraint, you should consider reorganizing your information into a different structure.

Comment: I wanted to just add a comment, but it said I had to have 50 rep to do so.  While I've had a login to StackOverflow for a while, I am just starting to attempt to contribute, which means I had less than 50 rep, so no ability to comment.

Comment: I did.. it looks like the author has already selected your answer which is giving him explicitly what he asked for.

Comment: Thank you for an alternative example.  While that may work, my intention was to make it a bit more scalable with as few declarations as possible.  

Use case for me will be specifying up to 52 weeks so creating up to 52 variables for a collection of days would require a lot more work than what I was looking for.

Looks like what I needed to figure out was how to use filters correctly to get what I was going for.

Thank you for your comment as I do like seeing alternative ways to a solution.

Comment: I was actually afraid you'd see that code and think that you needed to declare them like that.  You should be instantiating all the days/weeks/etc programmatically too.  That's way outside the scope of this question, though, and this is all just being inferred off of what you were asking.  In any event, glad you got your answer.